# Training an autoencoder across different machines

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, wireless, autoencoder

I am attempting to train an autoencoder to support wireless data transfer. The encoder portion will live on the transmitter side of the transceiver and the decoder will live on the receiver side. In general, the transmitter and receiver could be separated by miles and will exist on different computers.

The autoencoder must be trained using the real physical channel, therefore it will be necessary to perform backpropagation across two different computers (the transmitter and receiver computers). My question is, how can I start the process of back propagation on the receiver side, and finish it on the transmitter side?

To make this problem a little simpler, if you can help me perform backprop across two different files, that might be enough for me to extend it as needed. Imagine the encoder is defined by one file and the decoder is defined by another. How would I perform backprop across these two separate files?

I'm willing to use either pytorch or tensorflow, whichever is better suited to solve the problem. Pytorch would be my first choice if possible.

Here is pytorch code for a standard autoencoder that lives in one file and acts on CIFAR data. You can see how backpropagation is performed in one line loss.backward(). This is what won't work when the autoencoder is split between machines.

```
import torch
import torchvision as tv
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable

# Loading and Transforming data
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),  transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4466), (0.247,            0.243, 0.261))])
trainTransform  = tv.transforms.Compose([tv.transforms.ToTensor(), tv.transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4466), (0.247, 0.243, 0.261))])
trainset = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data',  train=True,download=True, transform=transform)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
testset = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

# Writing our model
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder,self).__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 6, kernel_size=5),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(6,16,kernel_size=5),
            nn.ReLU(True))
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16,6,kernel_size=5),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(6,3,kernel_size=5),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Sigmoid())
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

#defining some params
num_epochs = 5 #you can go for more epochs, I am using a mac
batch_size = 128

model = Autoencoder().cpu()
distance = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),weight_decay=1e-5)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for data in dataloader:
        img, _ = data
        img = Variable(img).cpu()
        # ===================forward=====================
        output = model(img)
        loss = distance(output, img)
        # ===================backward====================
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    # ===================log========================
    print('epoch [{}/{}], loss:{:.4f}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs, loss.data.numpy()))
```

Comment: possibly a dumb question, but it would help me understand: why do you need to use the real physical channel for training?

Comment: I am implementing an autoencoder that learns the channel without a channel model assumed. That means there is no functional form of the channel to apply gradient descent to for training. The training must occur with the real channel so the algorithm can estimate the gradients using the channel. The plus side to this is the transceiver adapts to whatever channel environment you put it in without any apriori channel modeling.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your example to test it more quickly. This is what I came up with

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class AE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AE,self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(20, 10),
                        nn.ReLU(True),
                        nn.Linear(10, 5),
                        nn.ReLU(True))
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(5, 10),
                        nn.ReLU(True),
                        nn.Linear(10, 20),
                        nn.ReLU(True),
                        nn.Sigmoid())

torch.manual_seed(0)
batch_size = 2
input_size = 20
epochs = 3

model = AE()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
x = torch.randn(batch_size, input_size)

for i in range(epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    code = model.encoder(x)

    # this would be where the code goes through your physical channel
    torch.save(code, 'code.pt')
    code_from_file = torch.load('code.pt')

    # compute the decoding with the code recovered on the other side
    reconstruction = model.decoder(code_from_file)
    loss = criterion(reconstruction, x)
    print("LOSS: ", loss)

    # this runs the backward pass up to code_from_file
    # because saving is non-differentiable and it has 
    # no knowledge of the computational graph before `code_from_file`
    loss.backward()  

    # here you would move the gradient of code_from_file through the channel
    torch.save(code_from_file.grad, 'code_grad.pt')
    code_grad = torch.load('code_grad.pt')
    # and recover it on the other side

    # feed the gradient to `code.backward` that will run backward pass up to the input
    code.backward(code_grad)
    # now you have the gradients for the encoder part and you can step
    optimizer.step()
```